# Dockerfile with multi stages rebuilds parts of previous stage

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I have this multistage Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.6 as base

ENV RAILS_ENV production

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    vim

RUN npm install -g yarn

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle config set --local deployment 'true'
RUN bundle config set --local without 'development test'
RUN bundle

RUN DB_ADAPTER=nulldb bundle exec rake assets:precompile

FROM base as app

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle

RUN DB_ADAPTER=nulldb bundle exec rake assets:precompile

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
```

I build `base` with:

```
docker build --target base -t base .
```

Then `app` with:

```
docker build --target app -t app .
```

Pretty straight forward.  The steps before `app` are slow, and I want to cache them.

Frequently (though not always - and no idea why) when I build `app` It will build steps after the first COPY in the `base` build.  Why is this?  Why isn't it just starting from the `base` image and building the later steps?

```
$ docker build --target app -t fapp .

Step 1/18 : FROM ruby:2.7.6 as base
 ---> f5dd208fb679
Step 2/18 : ENV RAILS_ENV production
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1891c50dd23b
Step 3/18 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2e8e284f77ec
Step 4/18 : RUN apt-get install -y     nodejs     npm     vim
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 70695d86c467
Step 5/18 : RUN npm install -g yarn
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 706a007e43c6
Step 6/18 : COPY . /app
 ---> ad3eb2821641
Step 7/18 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 7a7f83850b35
Removing intermediate container 7a7f83850b35
 ---> f9b1984c059a
Step 8/18 : RUN gem install bundler
 ---> Running in 29c9929d887d
Successfully installed bundler-2.3.15
1 gem installed
Removing intermediate container 29c9929d887d
 ---> 619dc2797660
Step 9/18 : RUN bundle config set --local deployment 'true'
 ---> Running in 36c4e27ae841
Removing intermediate container 36c4e27ae841
 ---> 33d6e03834b9
Step 10/18 : RUN bundle config set --local without 'development test'
 ---> Running in 94afe6d016e9
Removing intermediate container 94afe6d016e9
 ---> 90796cebb446
Step 11/18 : RUN bundle
 ---> Running in 9ea7167d9aff
```

Answer (score 0):

The docker cache can be easily invalidated from a `COPY` or `ADD` command, since the docker cache for these commands checks a hash of the files and directories.

Included in that hash are the contents of every file, and even the permissions on the files. So if any of these changed by a single byte, the hash will be different and docker will have a cache miss, forcing the line to be rerun.

From the point of the first cache miss, all remaining lines will need to be rebuilt since the preceding layer is now new and has not be used to run any of the following steps.

Comment: understood.  However, why did that first COPY run at all?  Why didn't it start at "FROM base as app" and use the 'base' image as a starting point?

Comment: @jsharpe, target means that it should stop at that stage, and use it as final image. It doesn't skip the stages beforehand, AFAIK.

Comment: Then whats the point of the "FROM" directive?